# Add Alarm using AlarmClock Or Alarmmanager , From User Input

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Am new to android app development

Need to turn on alarm from the user input data..

I have read about Alarmclock : Which can be used to set alarm to default clock app and it cannot be cancelled..

Alarmmanager : Used to trigger an event at specified time , but it has features of set or cancel the alarm

Idea: Using AlarmClock to set the alarm and cancel the alarm using Alarmmanager ..is it possible to do so

How can i do it .? help me out

Comment: So if I correctly get you, you are planning to set a alarm using the instance of `AlarmClock` and cancel the same alarm using the instance of `AlarmManager` class?

Comment: Yes , Parag Kadam . Is there any way to do it ,searched but couldnt find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the alarm you can do something like this:

```
        //... some code here

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // if you don't want the alarm to go off even in Doze mode, use
            // setExact instead
            mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    alarmTimeMillis,
                    getPendingIntent(context);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    alarmTimeMillis,
                    getPendingIntent(context);
        } else {
            // Inexact time was only introduced in API 19+. Before that, all was exact time
            mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    alarmTimeMillis,
                    getPendingIntent(context);
        }
```

Some words here. Before API 19, all alarms were exact, that's why we use `set` method. On API 19 and after, inexact alarms were introduced, that's the reason why we need to use `setExact` for *exact* alarms and `set` for *inexact* alarms.
In API 23, Doze mode was introduced. In that mode, any alarm set with `set` or `setExact` will not go off if the phone is already in doze mode. To force the device out of Doze and trigger the alarm, use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`

The method `getPendingIntent` could be something like this:

```
    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
        int requestCode = 69;
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode,
                new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

Of course, you can put extras into the intent as usual.

To cancel the alarm, you just need to create a pending intent with the same requestCode and call cancel on the alarm manager, something like:

```
(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
                      .cancel(getPendingIntent(context));
```

Please mind that the call above is far from perfect so, do not use it as is.

Answer (score 0):

to set the alarm, you need to create an intent which will be input for pendingIndent. This pendingIntent will go into alarm manager.

To cancel the alarm, create a pendingIntent will same requestCode/ID and then call alarmanager.cancel()

For full code of How to set alarm manger, please google the examples. There are plenty and almost each one of those examples are working-examples